# Yii installing x-editable on Yiistrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

In my web application I want to use x-editable for Yiistrap .I followed the steps as mentioned in the following link "http://x-editable.demopage.ru/". I am using Yiistrap which is working perfectly .But I am unable to install x-editable I am getting this error "Alias "editable.*" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file." "
My protected/config/main.php file

```
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',
'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'),


         'x-editable'=>realpath(__DIR__. '/../extensions/x-editable'),
    ),


    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
 'editable.*' //easy include of editable classes
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'***',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),

    ),
// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
     'editable' => array(
        'class'     => 'editable.EditableConfig',
        'form'      => 'bootstrap',        //form style: 'bootstrap', 'jqueryui', 'plain' 
        'mode'      => 'popup',            //mode: 'popup' or 'inline'  
        'defaults'  => array(              //default settings for all editable elements
           'emptytext' => 'Click to edit'
         ),
         ),
```

This is not the full code, the code I have to edit as mentioned in the tutorial which I  followed.

Answer (score 0):

On x-editable instruction:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('editable', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/x-editable');
```

Remove `x-` from this code:

```
'aliases' => array(
     // ...
     'editable'=>realpath(__DIR__. '/../extensions/x-editable'),
),
```